# Acoustic resonance in pipe

Tags: acoustics, resonance

This is quite a quick question. Would you call the acoustic resonance generated in pipes with a speaker to be caused by the *pipe* itself, or the *speaker*?

Comment: Would you say the collapse of the Tacoma Narrows Bridge was caused by the bridge itself or the wind hitting it?

Comment: The sound waves occurred first.

Comment: I would definitely say that the wind hitting the bridge caused it, but what about in the case of brass instruments where the vessel itself is designed to "create" those resonances with the instrumentalists' breath? Would this also mean that the instrumentalist is fully causing the resonance?

Comment: The speaker provides the attack, without it you cannot create any sound.  However, you do not get resonance until the driving frequency matches a normal mode of the pipe.  So one could argue that the pipe geometry has more to do with the "resonance" phenomenon than the source.